# Vuex mutation calling another mutation or a synchronous action instead?

Tags: vue.js, state, store, vuex

I am learning Vuex and have encountered a problem about structuring my app.

Consider these pieces of code, all of them doing the same thing:

Example #1:

```
mutations: {
  add: function(state, employee) {
    state.employees.push(employee);
  },
  remove: function(state, index) {
    state.employees.splice(index, 1);
  }
},
actions: {
  generate: function(context) {
    context.commit('add', 'John Smith');
  }
}
```

If actions are supposed to be asynchronous, then this is wrong.

Example #2:

```
mutations: {
  add: function(state, employee) {
    state.employees.push(employee);
  },
  remove: function(state, index) {
    state.employees.splice(index, 1);
  },
  generate: function(state) {
    this.commit('add', 'John Smith');
  }
}
```

Am I allowed to call a mutation from within another mutation? If not, then this is too wrong.

Example #3:

```
mutations: {
  add: function(state, employee) {
    state.employees.push(employee);
  },
  remove: function(state, index) {
    state.employees.splice(index, 1);
  },
  generate: function(state) {
    state.employees.push('John Smith');
  }
}
```

This on the other hand duplicates the logic - which seems wrong!

Example #4:

*Store*

```
mutations: {
  add: function(state, employee) {
    state.employees.push(employee);
  },
  remove: function(state, index) {
    state.employees.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
```

*Component*

```
methods: {
  addJohnSmith: function() {
    this.$store.commit('add', 'John Smith')
  },
}
```

This one seems okay, however I think this is the correct approach *only if all the input comes from the component*. What if I require this functionality to be controlled by the *store* instead, for example if I need to transform somehow this value? The component should be dumb enough to not care about this. A contrived example could be potentially adding a randomly generated title before the employee name, so the end result looks like this: Mr John Smith.

Which one would be the correct way to handle this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your first example is the correct structure.

It's true that any asynchronous code related to your Vuex module should be held in the module's actions and not in its mutations. But, actions are not *required* to be asynchronous.

They can contain synchronous code related to the module. This way, as you said in your last example, components referencing the Vuex module don't need to be aware of that internal logic.